# expand ViewTree after refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-extensions

I have a viewtree that's databound to an xml document, when the document is saved I call refresh on the datacontext and the ViewTree collapses, I really want the viewtree to not collaps, so I'm trying to write a function that unpacks it again.
Here I'm trying to use the xpath of the xml elements to reach the treeviewitems, however I can only get the root object, I suspect that's because 'ContainerFromItem' requires them to be visibly there rather than logically there?
But I don't know how else to do this.

This is the method that gets called after the datacontext has been refreshed

```
private void UnpackOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var pathStrings = node.Path.Split('/').ToList();
        pathStrings.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        for (int i = 0; i < pathStrings.Count; i++)
        {
            pathStrings[i] = pathStrings[i].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
            pathStrings[i] = pathStrings[i].Replace("[", "|").Replace("]", "");
        }

        ExpandTree(OutlineWindowInstance.TreeItems.ItemContainerGenerator, pathStrings, 0);
    }
}
```

This is a recursive function that's supposed to traverse all the previously open treeviewitems and expand them in the now refreshed tree.

```
void ExpandTree(ItemContainerGenerator itemses, List<string> treeNodes, int step)
{
    var name = treeNodes[step].Split('|')[0];
    var number = int.Parse(treeNodes[step].Split('|')[1])-1;
    var selected = itemses.Items.Cast<XmlElement>().Where(x => x.LocalName == name).ToList()[number];
    var selectedItem =((TreeViewItem) 
    //this is the line that is failing to do what I had hoped it would do
    itemses.ContainerFromItem(selected)); 
    if(selectedItem == null) return;
    selectedItem.IsExpanded = true;

    step++; 
    if (treeNodes.Count > step)
    {
        ExpandTree(selectedItem.ItemContainerGenerator, treeNodes, step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested ItemContainerGenerators are no fun to deal with... you have to utilize a lot of *start generating child items and wait for their completion before you start generating nested child items* with this approach. In my project I decided that I'd rather cheat by having a sort of `ViewBag` dictionary in my Viewmodel where I can store some arbitrary viewstate related properties.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I'm really very new to WPF and have been battling this 1 issue for over 2 weeks now xD

Comment: It's not that easy... in my case I had a dedicated viewmodel for every entry, while you load your data directly from some XML source as far as I can see. You should start by giving a full [mcve], then it might be clearer how we can help you.

Comment: Did you read and try this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-find-a-treeviewitem-in-a-treeview. It shows you how to realize a virtualized TreeViewItem.

Comment: I did not but I'm attempting to implement it now.

Comment: It took me a lot of fiddling, but I finally got it working thanks to the article mm8, thanks! :)

Comment: @TheLogan, If this issue has been resolved, you could post the solution as an answer, and mark it. So it could help other community members.

Comment: Ah, right, I've done so with a number of my other of my questions, I forgot it for this one, I'll do it asap! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this.
First I have a list of all current documents, for this I created the following class, it handles all things that have to do with the nodes for the document it represents

```
public class OpennedDocument
{
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ExpandedNodes;
    public bool IsRefreshing { get; set; }

    public void AddExpandedNode(string path)
    {
        if (IsRefreshing) return; //This stops it from registering a node during automatic expansion (after a refresh)
        ExpandedNodes.RemoveAll(path.Contains);
        ExpandedNodes.Add(path);
    }

    public void RemoveExpandedNode(string path)
    {
        var index = path.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if(IsRefreshing)return;
        ExpandedNodes.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(path));

        path = path.Remove(index);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            ExpandedNodes.Add(path);
    }
}
```

These methods are in the general manager script and ensure that all nodes in the treeview that were open before the refresh is openned again afterwards.

```
private void UnpackOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentDoc = Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DocName == dte.ActiveDocument.FullName);
    if (currentDoc == null) return;
    currentDoc.IsRefreshing = true;

    for (var index = 0; index < currentDoc.ExpandedNodes.Count; index++)
    {
        var node = currentDoc.ExpandedNodes[index];
        var pathStrings = node.Split('/').ToList();
        pathStrings.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        for (int i = 0; i < pathStrings.Count; i++)
        {
            pathStrings[i] = pathStrings[i].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
            pathStrings[i] = pathStrings[i].Replace("[", "|").Replace("]", "");
        }

        ExpandTree(OutlineWindowInstance.TreeItems.ItemContainerGenerator, pathStrings, 0,
            OutlineWindowInstance.TreeItems);
    }

    currentDoc.IsRefreshing = false;
}

void ExpandTree(ItemContainerGenerator itemses, List<string> treeNodes, int step, ItemsControl last)
{
    while (true)
    {
        last.UpdateLayout();
        var name = treeNodes[step].Split('|')[0];
        var number = int.Parse(treeNodes[step].Split('|')[1]) - 1;
        var selected = itemses.Items.Cast<XmlElement>().Where(x => x.LocalName == name).ToList()[number];
        var selectedItem = ((TreeViewItem) itemses.ContainerFromItem(selected));
        if (selectedItem == null) return;
        selectedItem.IsExpanded = true;

        step++;
        if (treeNodes.Count > step)
        {
            itemses = selectedItem.ItemContainerGenerator;
            last = selectedItem;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```